# How to solve $xy'+x=y\ln(xy)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i.e. $x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+x=y\ln(xy)$.
The MATHEMATICA can't solve this problem.

```
DSolve[x*y'[x]+x==y[x]*Log[y[x]*x],y[x],x]
```

leads

```
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

Comment: Use NDSolve instead...